# Api service with changing arguments using Observables in Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

The behaviour I want: when a user selects a Label from dropdown menu, api is called with that Label as an argument and a chart is redrawn using data received from api. There are multiple identical charts in the page with their respective drop down lists.
The problem is that my solution is not working and I'm not sure how to make it work. My solution:

### Chart component

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

    private _label = new ReplaySubject<string>()
    //Gets value from dropdown menu
    @Input() set label(value: string) {this._label.next(value)}

    apiSub: Subscription

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.apiSub = this.apiService
        .getData(this._label)
        .subscribe(this.redrawGraph.bind(this),
            console.error
        )
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.apiSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    redrawGraph(data:Data[]){
        //Chart drawing logic
    }
}
```

### Api service

```
export class ApiService {

    response= new ReplaySubject<Observable<Data[]>>()

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    private static _handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
        return Observable.throw(err.message || 'Error: Unable to connect to API.');
    }


    getData( label: Observable<string> ): Observable<Data[]> {
        label.subscribe(label => {
            this.response.next(this.http
            .get<Data[]>(`${Urls.DATA}?label=${label}`)
            .catch(ApiService._handleError));
        })

        return this.response.mergeMap(x => x)
    }
```

Now redrawGraph() is only called the first time label changes. And there's obviously bad behaviour when several graphs are present, because service is a singleton as far as I know, but I don't know how else to return response without binding it to "this".

What I'm trying to avoid is having to subscribe/unsubscribe to api method from Chart component every time label changes and instead just have one stream: label changes -> api call -> chart redrawn. So how to do it properly?

Comment: the initial action should be trigger by select option even. Your code is not structured correctly. selectEvent -> pick up label -> pass to api call

Comment: @FanCheung Are you saying, that it's bad that I'm creating ReplaySubject from input variable?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you need create individual subject for each chart.
The code will looks like this:

```
getData( label: Observable<string> ): Observable<Data[]> {
    let response : Subject = Subject<Data[]>();
    label.subscribe(label => {
        response.next(this.http
        .get<Data[]>(`${Urls.DATA}?label=${label}`)
        .catch(ApiService._handleError));
    })

    return response;
}
```

Comment: But this.response refers to class field, so response defined here doesn't get used

Comment: In my example the response is created in getData function. As I uindestood you need several responses for several charst. With one instance of response it will not work for several instances.

Comment: I mean "let response" and later "this.response" are two different variables (because of scope), so "return response" just returns that empty "Subject<Data[]>()

Comment: Agree, I have fix the issue